# Prove that $P(A \cup B) \geq 1 - P(A^c) - P(B^c)$.

Tags: probability, elementary-set-theory

I'm not sure how to start this problem. I can kind of see why this is true but I don't know how to show it. Any suggestions about how to start it would be appreciated!

Comment: You know that $P(X) = 1 - P(X^c)$, so you have $P(A \cup B) = 1 - P((A \cup B)^c)$. $(A \cup B)^c$ is the set of things neither in $A$ nor $B$, or in other words $A^c \cap B^c$. That's a significant portion of the solution.

Answer (score 3):

Here are two key facts to solve this exercise:

1. $P(A\cup B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cap B)$
2. $P(E)+P(E^c)=1$ where $E$ is any event in the sample space.

Comment: I actually just finished proving those exact two things! haha I wasn't even thinking about them in respect to this problem!

Comment: Then that's good you proved it!